# Subclass ViewController from Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I created ViewController in Storyboard and I am using

```
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
```

to load it. But I need to have this VC as base class and use 3-4 subclasses to change its properties.

How can I get an instance of my subclass with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`?

Comment: Here is your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022258/ios-present-viewcontroller-getting-black-screen/28022449#28022449)!

Answer (score 20):

@Bhagyesh version in **Swift 3**:

```
class func instantiateFromSuperclassStoryboard() -> SubclassViewController {
    let stroryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = stroryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BaseViewController")
    object_setClass(controller, SubclassViewController.self)

    return controller as! SubclassViewController
}
```

Comment: Be careful it can cause `swift_unknownObjectWeakDestroy` crash. See Jon's comment  above.

Answer (score 7):

You will have to use object c runtime. Override init method of your subclass. Create a BaseViewController object using 'instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier'. Then set the class for created object using objc_setClass method.
Following code will go into SubclassViewController.m.

```
    - (instancetype)init {
      UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
      UIViewController *baseClassViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"baseClassIdentifier"];

      object_setClass(baseClassViewController, [SubclassViewController class]);
      return (SubclassViewController *)baseClassViewController;
    }
```

After this, you can simply create SubclassViewController object using simple [[SubclassViewController alloc] init].

Comment: Sadly, this crashes if the subclass contains any extra instance variables. That's because `object_setClass` simply changes the `isa` pointer. It doesn't allocate any extra space. As soon as you try to access an additional variable, boom.

Answer (score -1):

Just cast it.

```
MyController *controller = (MyController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myController"];
```

or Swift:

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myController") as! MyController
```

Comment: But if I need to create MyControllerSubclass1 that subclass of MyController from storyboard with id "myController"?

Comment: Whatever ID you gave the view controller in the storyboard.

Comment: No, that won't work in that case, you will get a runtime error: `Could not cast value of type 'YourApp.BaseViewController' (0x10e435d48) to 'YourApp.SubclassViewController' (0x10e435a68).`