# How to implement a BaseViewController through storyboard or xib?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xib, abstraction

Wait, I know this question title looks very duplicated, but it really is not.
I have been searching for whole day but cannot find any good solution.

#### Definition of terms

`BaseViewController`: A class that extends `UIViewController`, responsible for some common behaviors across different subclassed ViewControllers.
`VC`: Short form of ViewController, I will use it from now on
`dialog`: In other words, popup; a VC that does not cover the whole screen, and is present modally.

#### Scenario

Let me use an example to illustrate my needs.

Let say I have an app that displays dialogs in different places.
These dialogs have something in common, including:

1. They will blur the background when displayed
2. They have a same width
3. They have a same dialog container style (e.g. rounded corner radius)

And they also have non common things - the content inside the dialog container.

In order to reduce code duplication, I want to create a `BaseDialogVC` to implement the above 3 common things first, and then child class that subclass `BaseDialogVC` will provide the view inside the container.

Therefore, I created a storyboard file which contains `BaseDialogVC` and implemented the 3 common things using Interface Builder of storyboard.
It has an empty `UIView` that acts as a container for its child class to provide their content.
And then, I created a subclass of `BaseDialogVC`, for example, `AddItemDialogVC`. This `AddItemDialogVC` is then responsible for providing its content view, and the logic of this dialog.

Then I am stuck - I tried to instantiate from storyboard an `AddItemDialogVC`, but it will crash because storyboard does not have `AddItemDialogVC`. It only has `BaseDialogVC`.

#### Question

Actually, I know one alternative that can achieve similar things.
That is - I **do not subclass** `BaseDialogVC`, instead I instantiate it, and add subview to it by calling an instance method of it, passing in an `UIView`.

But I still very much want to know what's wrong with my original approach, or,
What is the best approach to this problem?

By "the best approach", I mean it effectively reduced duplication and is easy to maintain.

#### What I have tried

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45736186/7870874) for changing `BaseDialogVC` to `AddItemDialogVC`. But even if it successfully created an `AddItemDialogVC`, the `AppItemDialogVC` cannot init its content view (A custom View that is subclass of `UIView`, and I got an "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" exception.

I think the most similar question out there is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111572/how-to-use-single-storyboard-uiviewcontroller-for-multiple-subclass).
However, the accepted answer does not elaborate enough; while the second most voted answer is the same as `set_object` that I have tried before.

FYI, my class for `AddItemDialogView` (NOT VC!):

```
class AddChoiceDialogView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var rootView: AddChoiceDialogView!

    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init? (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit () {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AddChoiceDialogView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(rootView)
        rootView.frame = self.bounds
        rootView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }

}
```

Comment: Similar to your alternative idea, it seems to me that your `BaseDialogVC` provides structure but needs a delegate or data source to customize its content.

Comment: A delegate! I obviously didn't think of that. But I cannot figure out the whole picture yet - I suppose the one that provides the delegate is a subclass of `BaseDialogVC`, if I am still using storyboard to create the structure of the dialog, how am I going to instantiate that subclass correctly?

Comment: I don't think there's any need for the delegate to be a subclass.  I'd think of `BaseDialogVC` as a `DialogPresenterVC` or something like that instead.  It can ask the delegate for data to display or even a view to display if that's a better fit.

Comment: Now I understand your point. But think of it, I think I really need a subclass. Because I do not only need to provide the content (View), I also need to handles the corresponding logic of the dialog.

Comment: OK, if you need view-specific logic, make your base dialog a container controller and provide it with a view controller to embed.  (By the way, what's wrong with having the child controllers available in the storyboard if you want subclassing?)

Comment: @PhillipMills VC Container, that is another option to explore as well. I came up with one possible solution that I will give it a try: `BaseDialogVC` subclass `UIViewController`, but not referencing any storyboard. And init a subview from xib to `self.view`. From there on, `AddItemDialogVC` subclass `BaseDialogVC` and populates the content view. Does it sound make sense to you? As for what's wrong with having the child controllers in storyboard - I just want to reduce duplication of common characteristics they have. If that is a large project, that would be a mess if I want to change the bg